# How to tell if a model has simple-history records?

Tags: django-simple-history

I need a way to tell if a model has simple-history `HistoricalRecord`.

A bad way is to check is seeing if `self.history` exists but I don't like that because the developer doesn't have to use use history as the attribute name for the `HistoricalRecord`.

Alternatively I could try to loop through `dir(model)` but this runs into issues where a related name reverse lookup could result in a `DoesNotExist` exception. I could try to catch the exception but ugh that is ugly.

I need this because I'd like to add a link in django admin to a special view I made to look at simple history records and I want to display the link only if the model has `HistoricalRecords`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around, it appears that simple-history keeps a record of all the models that have historical objects! How convenient! The solution to this problem can be something like

```
from simple_history import models

def has_simple_history(obj):
    return obj.__class__ in models.registered_models.values()
```